# getting international time using javascript/jquery/json/etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out some way to get actual time via JavaScript, jQuery, JSON, etc...

I've got these two sites that host the time for exactly that purpose

- http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
- http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

and this site that actualy explains how to get the time but i cant seem to figure it out, since i dont really know json, only javascript.

- http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/getting-the-real-time-in-javascript/

I've searched a lot but couldn't figure out how to extract data from another website using JavaScript.

if someone could help me get the time from one of these sites into a variable in JavaScriptthat would be great.thanks.

Comment: If you just want to get the current time on the client, you can just run var date = new Date(), which will generate a Date object, on which you can find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this right in the console if you're using chrome or firefox:

```
jQuery.ajax({dataType:'jsonp',
             url:'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=Europe/London',
             success:function(data){x=data;console.log(x);}})
```

You'll see that x now contains the json time object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get the time Now, of your current location?
If so, you can use the standard javascript `new Date()` as such:

```
var xx = new Date();
hour = xx.getHours();
min = xx.getMinutes();
time = hour + ':' + min;
console.log(time);
```

See example here:
http://jsbin.com/esaxel/2/edit

This just logs it to the console, but you could easily apply it to a div or some other element.

edit: here's a sample of putting it in a div, I also fixed the variable declarations:
http://jsbin.com/esaxel/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery library I just looked at that tutorial and with very minor modification this works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getTime = function(zone, success) {
    var url = 'http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz='
            + zone + '&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function(o){
        success && success(o.datetime);
    });
};

// Usage:
function doit(){
    $.getTime('America/Detroit', function(time){
    alert(time);
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){ $('#summat').click(doit); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summat">CLICK ME</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the variable 'time' is the string of local time and date for given timezone i.e. America/Detroit.